# How to get event name of notification from DRIVE API using drive push notification?

Tags: java, web-applications, push-notification, google-drive-api, drive

I have implemented the google drive push notifications in Java, for receiving the notification I have created the channel see below code :

```
        notificationchannel.setAddress("https://www.XXXXXX.in/drive/receive/notifications");
        notificationchannel.setType("web_hook");
        notificationchannel.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        notificationchannel.setExpiration(new Date().getTime() + 86340000);

        userDriveService = (Drive)inUtilityObj.getDriveService(userEmail);

        if(userDriveService != null) {
            StartPageToken pageToken = userDriveService.changes().getStartPageToken().execute();
            Channel changesChannel   = userDriveService.changes().watch(pageToken.getStartPageToken(), notificationchannel).execute();
        }
```

The channel is created successfully and when i change or remove or upload file of drive i am getting same notifications for all event from google drive.
Below is my notification listener code :

```
   try {
        String nextPageToken = savedStartPageToken;
        while (nextPageToken != null) {
          ChangeList changes = driveService.changes().list(nextPageToken).execute();
          log.warning(" *** ChangeList ::" + changes.getChanges());
          for (Change changeObj : changes.getChanges()) {
              log.warning("File Id::"+changeObj.getFileId() + ",Kind ::"+changeObj.getKind() + ", Team Drive ID::"+changeObj.getTeamDriveId() + ", Type::"+changeObj.getType()+ ",File ::"+changeObj.getFile()+ ", Is Removed::"+changeObj.getRemoved()+ ",Time ::"+changeObj.getTime());
          }
          if (changes.getNewStartPageToken() != null) {
            // Last page, save this token for the next polling interval
            savedStartPageToken = changes.getNewStartPageToken(); // store in database
            log.warning("savedStartPageToken ::" + savedStartPageToken);
          }
          nextPageToken = changes.getNextPageToken();
          log.warning("nextPageToken ::" + nextPageToken);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ErrorHandler.errorHandler(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), ex);
    }
```

How can I get event name in notification response from google drive?

example : if i close the file then event name in response like close etc.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the way of getting notification with event name, I have found that:

1. There is no way to get event name using changes watch request.
2. We can get event name in notification using file watch request.

Feel free to visit the article on [making watch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push#making-watch-requests) for more information.